# UIActivityIndicator not working

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, xcode5.1

I have View with TableView, I want to show activity indicator when I do something but he don't show, I found this code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView =
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(120, 230, 50, 50);
[self.ReportTableView addSubview:activityView];

[activityView startAnimating];
```

No errors but and now indicator show.

**Solution:**

```
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Comment: animate it after adding to the View

Comment: i suggest to use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) that less code and working fine.

Comment: just remove the last [self.ReportTableView addSubview:activityView];

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik remove and still nothing.

Comment: just add the another one line [self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityView]; bz it shows in front of all view

Comment: also change UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView =
    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your tableview backgrond color is white then it will not show because UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite is also white

```
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

Change to

```
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont add activity inside the tableview.Add it in the main view or the superview of table

Dont forget to update the frame accordingly to where you add it

```
[self.ReportTableView.superView addSubview:activityView];
[self.ReportTableView.superView bringSubviewToFront:activityView];
```

Comment: Try - [self.view addSubview:activityView]; and still not working.

Comment: Also add [self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityView];

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your code
[activityView startAnimating];

[self.ReportTableView addSubview:activityView];

Move [activityView startAnimating]; after

[self.ReportTableView addSubview:activityView];
```

Order is very important

Comment: Change but nothing happen, still don't see indicator.